# Let $f(x)=4x^3-3x^2-2x+1,$ use Rolle's theorem to prove that there exist $c,0<c<1$ such that $f(c)=0$

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=4x^3-3x^2-2x+1,$ use Rolle's theorem to prove that there exist $c,0<c<1$ such that $f(c)=0$

---

$f(x)=4x^3-3x^2-2x+1,$ is continuous and differentiable but the third condition of 
Rolle's theorem is not met,so Rolle's theorem is not applicable here.
I am stuck here.

Comment: $f(c)=0$ or $f'(c)=0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $g(x)=x^4-x^3-x^2+x$. Then $g'(x)=f(x)$.

$g(0)=g(1)=0$.

By Rolle's Theorem, there exist $c$ such that $0<c<1$ and $g'(c)=0$.